# Google Sheets Utilities.parseCsv function only returning string values

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, type-conversion, custom-function

I have a custom function in Google Sheets which is generally working fine, and returns a csv when called. However, all the values are returning as text and not as their general data type i.e. numbers are not numbers. For example, if I try to check if 3 = cell D5, the value is false.

Is there something I can add to my script to convert specific columns to values?

Here's a snip of the code:

```
if (resultPath) {
   var csvPath = 'https://modeanalytics.com' + resultPath + '/content.csv'
   var csvResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvPath, options);
   var csvTextRaw = csvResponse.getContentText();
   var csvText = csvTextRaw.replace(/([“'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2[\s\S])*?\1/g, function(e){return e.replace(/\r?|\r/g, ' ') });

   return Utilities.parseCsv(csvText)

 } else {
   return 'Invalid URL!'
 }
```

[image]

Comment: multiply by 1 or use `Number()` or ``parseInt``

Comment: I think that @I'-'I 's comment is correct. So for example, how about modifying from ``return Utilities.parseCsv(csvText)`` to ``return Utilities.parseCsv(csvText).map(function(row){return row.map(function(col){return isNaN(col) ? col : Number(col)})})``?

Comment: @Tanaike thanks so much! That worked perfectly. I also have a column that has a date field, which is now returning as a number. Is there a way to solve that issue as well?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was solved.